# Переопределение, различные базовые типы

Tags: c

возникает такая ошибка : opt : переопределение; различные базовые типы. Не понимаю, что не так, спасибо!

```
void generation(int size, int* cur_res) {
    for (int i = min[size]; i <= max[size]; i++) {
        if (size == 9) {
            opt(0, 0, cur_res);
            continue;
        }
        generation(size + 1, cur_res);
    }
    return;
}

void opt(int first, int cur_sum, int* cur_res) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Вы вроде как 3 месяца на ruSO - неужели до сих пор не сталкивались с тем, что код надо давать текстом, а не картинкой?..

Comment: @Harry, поправил, теперь буду знать :)

Comment: У вас и в программе `opt` объявляется после `generation` или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вангую, что `opt` объявлена после использования в `generation`.

Соответственно, C-компилятор считает, что это будет какая-то функция, возвращающая `int` и с типами параметров, соответствующими аргументам.

После чего встречается с функцией с тем же именем, но возвращающей `void`...

Объявите функцию `opt` до `generation`. Делать ее `int` не рекомендую :)

Comment: Да! Спасибо большое